# How to store variables that can be accessed and modified across pages and components with Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-context

I am writing an app using the Ionic Framework and React. It's a multi-page app that I'm using IonReactRouter and Routes to handle navigation for. The app needs to keep track of a language preference (english or spanish) and instead of passing down it through props through my many pages and components, I'm trying to figure out how to store it as a global variable. I will also be working on allowing the user to add tables, and would like to store their data in a database (using the SQlite plug in potentially) so I'm thinking I need some sort of context or store to handle both.

Here's what I've tried:

- Using React Context, both with hooks in functional components and in class components. I've tried consuming the state with
  static contextType = AppContext;
  and then referring to this.context to consume the state, and I've used hooks as well, but neither have worked properly.

I'll include what I have right now.
I believe in the page that manipulates th

Here's my App.js

```
    export default class App extends Component{
    
      constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.site = "baja";
    this.setLanguage = (lang) => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        language: lang
      }));
    };
    this.state = {
      language: "english",
      setLanguage: this.setLanguage,
    };
  }
    
      render(){
        return(
            <AppContextProvider value>
              <IonApp>
                <IonReactRouter>
                  <IonRouterOutlet>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home/sections" />} />
                 <Route path="/speciesList/community/:name/:community"
                       strict={true}
                       render={(props) => <SpeciesList community={true} site={this.site} {...props}/>}/>
// there's a lot of routes here but I only included the relevant ones
<Route path="/home/:tab"
                       strict={true}
                       render={(props) => <Home site={this.site} {...props}/>}/>
                  </IonRouterOutlet>
                </IonReactRouter>
              </IonApp>
            </AppContextProvider>
        );
      }
    }
```

And my AppContext.js

```
import React from 'react';
export const AppContext = React.createContext({
    language: "english",
    setLanguage: () => {}
});
```

And the component I'm modifying context with

```
class TranslationButton extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {({language, setLanguage}) => (
                    <IonRadioGroup color="dark" value={language} onIonChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.detail.value)}>
                        <IonItem><IonLabel>Set Language</IonLabel></IonItem>
                        <IonItem><IonLabel>English</IonLabel><IonRadio slot="start" value="english"/></IonItem>
                        <IonItem><IonLabel>Español</IonLabel><IonRadio slot="start" value="espanol"/></IonItem>
                    </IonRadioGroup>
                )}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        )
    }

}

export default TranslationButton;
```

The component that reflects changes to the context language:

```
export default class SectionsTab extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {({language, setLanguage}) => (
                    <>
                        <Toolbar site={this.props.site} title="Home" history={this.props.history} language={this.context}/>
                        <IonContent fullscreen>
                            {language}
                            <PageList title="Sections"
                                      site={this.props.site}
                                      items={(this.props.site === "pingree") ? pingree_sections : baja_sections}/>
                        </IonContent>
                    </>
                    )}
            </AppContext.Consumer>

        )
    }
}
```

The component that does not show the correct context language after changing it:

```
class SpeciesList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nameOrder: "scientific",
            alphabetOrder: "a-z",
            sortOpen: false
        }
        this.category = this.props.match.params.name;
        if(this.props.community)
            this.community = this.props.match.params.community;
        if(this.props.family)
            this.family = this.props.match.params.family;
        this.section = new Section(this.category, this.family, this.community, props.site);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
            {({language, setLanguage}) => (
            <IonPage>
                <Toolbar site={this.props.site} history={this.props.history} title={this.section.title}/>
                <IonContent fullscreen>
                    {language}
                    {this.renderSortButton()}
                    <IonList>
                        {this.section.data.map((item, index) =>
                            <IonItem href={getURL(index, this.category)} key={index}>
                                <IonThumbnail item-left><img alt={item.species} src={findThumbnail(item, this.props.site, this.category)}/></IonThumbnail>
                            {this.renderLabel(item)}
                            </IonItem>)
                            }
                    </IonList>
                </IonContent>
            </IonPage>)}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        );
    };
```

And then when I try to just access and display the context, I use a similar thing as above, using the AppContextConsumer tag and then referring to language. The thing is, in the page that is the parent (or grandparent, somewhere upwards in terms of rendering) of the TranslationButton.js component above, the context is correctly consumed, and when I change the language in the context, that's reflected. But, in a separate page (SpeciesList) that consumes the context in the same way, it doesn't reflect the change based on the user action with the button in TranslationButton. I'm not sure if navigating to a different page rerenders everything and resets the context or what, but I'm not sure what's happening.

In terms of the components - the SpeciesList is a page (loaded with the route) and the TranslationButton is rendered by a Toolbar which is rendered by the SectionsTab class. So I don't know if the nested components matter either.